# Transform Function Component to a Class Component

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am still learning React and I am wondering if it is possible to make the function component below into a class component.

Component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Navbar from "./navbar"

const Layout = ({ location, title, children }) => {
  const rootPath = `${__PATH_PREFIX__}/`
  const [classNames, setClassNames] = useState('')
  const updateClasses = (classNames) => {
    setClassNames(classNames)
  }
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          menuLinks {
            link
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar pages={ data.site.siteMetadata.menuLinks } updateClassNames={updateClasses} />
      <main className={classNames}>{children}</main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

My biggest issue is with the parameters that are passed to the function `location, title, children`. What will happen with them. I am not using them at the moment, but will need them later.

Answer (score 1):

Class or function component is not much different except using hooks.
With your current function component, just use the `location`, `title`, etc `props` like other variables in a normal function.

Why do you need to convert into class component?

Comment: I am trying lift up a state from the Navbar component. Edit: Correct me if I am wrong, but I need a class to do that.

Comment: For example, I'll show you how to "lift something from child to parent" with function component.


Look at `setSomeState` function at here (just to show the way): https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-glade-w589u?file=/src/App.js:0-379

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a class component to lift up a class, value, or any data in a child component, it's the same behavior rather than class-based component or functional component. You just need to pass via props a function that it will be triggered in a child component to lift up some data again to the parent.

In your parent component, you need to set the function. Without knowing its structure, it would look like:

```
someFunction= value => {
   console.log('I have the value: ', value)
}

return <Layout someFunction={someFunction}
```

*Disclaimer: you may need to adapt the code to your component. The idea is to set a function and pass it via props in the `return`.*

Then, in your `<Layout>` component, you can destructure the function as you do with `location`, `title` and `children`, and trigger when you need it:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Navbar from "./navbar"

const Layout = ({ location, title, children, someFunction }) => {
  const rootPath = `${__PATH_PREFIX__}/`
  const [classNames, setClassNames] = useState('')
  const updateClasses = (classNames) => {
    setClassNames(classNames)
  }

  const handleClick=()=>{
    someFunction('hello')
  }
  
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          menuLinks {
            link
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar pages={ data.site.siteMetadata.menuLinks } updateClassNames={updateClasses} onClick={()=>handleClick} />
      <main className={classNames}>{children}</main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

In this dummy example, you will be passing `'hello'` to the parent component when the `<Navbar>` is clicked, of course, you can pass any desired value or use a `useEffect` hook or whatever you need. This is the way to pass data from child to parent component.